# How to show a webgrid in popup window on button click on this window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on such a application in which I have to choose question type in a popup window and after choosing type, I supposed to click OK button which will display a webGrid of multiple Questions. Since I have created popup and it's working well and while I click on OK button, the window get normal.

As my code for popup is

```
//Link
@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "AddDependentQuestion", "Question",
new { QuestionID = question.QuestionID }, 
new { @class = "openDialog",   data_dialog_title = "Dependent Question" })


 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
           $("#popup")
addClass("dialog")
           .attr("id", $(this)
)
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
close: function () { $(this).remove() },
modal: true
                })
.load(this.href);
           alert(this.href);
});

       $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
           $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
});
   });
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit. WINDOW get normal is too generic and please can you be bit specific.

Comment: @mohanrajt Actually the problem is, when i click on OK button it suppose to show  webgrid as per my logic but as i click on button it open this page in new window.